# Confusion with the external tables in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, create-table, external-tables, hiveddl

I have created the hive external table using below command:

```
 use hive2;

create external table depTable (depId int comment 'This is the unique id for each dep', depName string,location string) comment 'department table' row format delimited fields terminated by "," 
stored as textfile location '/dataDir/';
```

Now, when I view the HDFS I can see the db but there is no `depTable` inside the warehouse.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hive2.db
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Above you can see that there is no table created in this DB. As far as I know, external tables are not stored in the hive warehouse.So am I correct ?? If yes then where is it stored ??
But if I create external table first and then load the data then I am able to see the file inside `hive2.db`.

```
hive> create external table depTable (depId int comment 'This is the unique id for each dep', depName string,location string) comment 'department table' row format delimited fields terminated by "," stored as textfile;
OK
Time taken: 0.056 seconds
hive> load data inpath '/dataDir/department_data.txt' into table depTable;
Loading data to table default.deptable
Table default.deptable stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=90]
OK
Time taken: 0.28 seconds
hive> select * from deptable;
OK
1001    FINANCE SYDNEY
2001    AUDIT   MELBOURNE
3001    MARKETING   PERTH
4001    PRODUCTION  BRISBANE
```

Now, if I fire the `hadoop fs` query I can see this table under database as below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hive2.db
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2019-01-17 09:07 /user/hive/warehouse/hive2.db/deptable
```

If I delete the table still I am able to see table in the HDFS as below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/hive2.db
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2019-01-17 09:11 /user/hive/warehouse/hive2.db/deptable
```

So, what is the exact behavior of the external tables ?? When I create using `LOCATION` keyword where does it get stored and when I create using `load` statement why it is getting stored in the `HDFS` and after deleting why it doesn't get deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The main difference between `EXTERNAL` and `MANAGED` tables is in Drop table/partition behavior.**
When you drop `MANAGED` table/partition, the location with data files also removed.
When you drop `EXTERNAL` table, the location with data files remains as is.

**UPDATE:** `TBLPROPERTIES ("external.table.purge"="true")` in release 4.0.0+ ([HIVE-19981](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19981)) when set on external table would delete the data as well.

**`EXTERNAL` table as well as `MANAGED` is being stored in the location specified in DDL**. You can create table on top of existing location with data files already in the location and it will work for both `EXTERNAL` or `MANAGED`, does not matter.

You even can create both `EXTERNAL` and `MANAGED` tables on top of the same location, see this answer with more details and tests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038932/2700344

If you specified location, the data will be stored in that location for both types of tables. If you did not specify location, the data will be in default location: `/user/hive/warehouse/database_name.db/table_name` for both managed and external tables.

Update: Also there can be some restrictions on location depending on platform/vendor, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073849/2700344, you may not be allowed to create manged/external tables outside their default allowed root location.

See also official Hive docs on [Managed vs External Tables](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Managed+vs.+External+Tables)

Comment: I created the external table pointing towards the data in HDFS but, I can't see it in warehouse folder . So my question is where does the external table gets stored ?? and if I create external table using load command it behaves as managed table. Can you help me here ?

Comment: Your answer didn't help me. I know about the basic concepts and all but had some doubts regarding the storage in HDFS. I hope I am loud and clear

Comment: @RushHour What is the location '/dataDir/' means ? It should be HDFS dir in both cases. Iocal dir cannot be table location

Comment: yeah I know that but my question is different. Why I am not able to see existing external table in the warehouse?? Is there some different directory to see it ??

Comment: @RushHour create external table does not create folder, only modifies metadata. After you loaded file, it appeared in HDFS

Comment: Okay but when I create external table using load command and then I try to delete it, it gets deleted from hive but in HDFS warehouse it still shows the table under warehouse folder . why is it so ?? Could you please try it on my behalf ??

Comment: @RushHour I already explained this in my answer. Because it is external table. You created external table and loaded data. Then you deleted table and data remain untouched- this how external table works

Comment: Then why it gets deleted from hive since it is an external table it shouldn't get deleted

Comment: Only table is deleted (why shouldn't it? It should if you do drop table), data remains untouched in hdfs. Hive table - is a metastore information about table schema, location with data, statistics, table type=External, etc. Data is in HDFS. When you delete External table in Hive, only table get deleted, not data

Comment: Ok understood finally . Thanks for answering my stupid questions, mate :)