# Unable to create Managed Hive Table after Hortonworks (HDP) to Cloudera (CDP) migration

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdp

We are testing our Hadoop applications as part of migrating from Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP v3.x) to Cloudera Data Platform (CDP) version 7.1. While testing, we found below issue while trying to create Managed Hive Table. Please advise on possible solutions. Thank you!

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. MetaException(message:**A managed table's location should be located within managed warehouse root directory or within its database's managedLocationUri**. Table MANAGED_TBL_A's location is not valid:hdfs://cluster/prj/Warehouse/Secure/APP/managed_tbl_a, managed warehouse:hdfs://cluster/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive) (state=08S01,code=40000)

DDL Script

```
create table if not exists MANAGED_TBL_A
(
   name string,
   id varchar(20),
   created_on TIMESTAMP,
   created_by VARCHAR(10)
)
partitioned by (partition_date varchar(20))
clustered by (id) into 5 buckets
stored as orc
location '/prj/Warehouse/Secure/APP/managed_tbl_a'
tblproperties ('compactorthreshold.hive.compactor.delta.num.threshold'='1','compactorthreshold.hive.compactor.delta.pct.threshold'='0.5','transactional'='true','orc.create.index'='true','orc.compress.size'='8192');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` - is a warehouse root directory.

When you create the database, specify `MANAGEDLOCATION` - a location root for managed tables and `LOCATION` - root for external tables.

`MANAGEDLOCATION` is within  `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`

Setting the `metastore.warehouse.tenant.colocation` property to `true` allows a common location for managed tables (MANAGEDLOCATION) outside the warehouse root directory, providing a tenant-based common root for setting quotas and other policies.

See more details in this manual: [Hive managed location](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.7/using-hiveql/topics/hive_managed_location.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. After setting MANAGEDLOCATION pointing to root of the Table location, it worked!! (alter database testDB set managedlocation 'hdfs://cluster/prj/Warehouse/';)