# unable to create internal hive table

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive, ubuntu-20.04

i am getting below error while trying to create hive internal table

```
CREATE TABLE employee(id INT,Name STRING);
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/user/hive/warehouse/employee is not a directory or unable to create one)

i have created user/hive/warehouse directory in HDFS location and given below permission also

hadoop@raja-VirtualBox:~$ hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/
Found 1 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hadoop supergroup          0 2022-01-21 16:19 /user/hive/warehouse

below is the screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEIcf.png)

still i am getting error

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073849/2700344

Comment: i am not using cloudera , i have installed native apache hive 3.1.2 in ubuntu 20.4, So by default when we try to create a table it should point user/hive/warehouse and create table automatically