# Hive managed table issue to create a hive table from a hdfs location in CDP

Tags: hive, sqoop, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-cdp, cdp

I have a CDP 7.3.1 where using sqoop , I have loaded data from Postgres database table into HDFS location /ts/gp/node. Now I am trying to create a hive table on this. I get the below error. Please help

```
CREATE TABLE dsk.node
(
    district  string,
    zone  string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/ts/gp/node'
ERROR: ImpalaRuntimeException: Error making 'createTable' RPC to Hive Metastore:
CAUSED BY: MetaException: A managed table's location should be located within managed warehouse root directory or within its database's managedLocationUri. Table node's location is not valid:hdfs://gFasService/ts/gp/node, managed warehouse:hdfs://gFasService/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67073849/2700344

Comment: I saw that. But Im not sure how to use it in my context. Could you elaborate from my context?. I have already loaded data to the HDFS path here in my case under '/ts/gp/node'

Comment: Also, I get the below error when I try using the alter database command.
```
alter database dsk set managedlocation 'hdfs://gFasService/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive';
Query: alter database dsk set managedlocation 'hdfs://gFasService/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive'
ERROR: ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
alter database dsk set managedlocation 'hdfs://gFas...
                       ^
Encountered: MANAGEDLOCATION
Expected: IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

Comment: The simple way: create table without location specified, describe formatted to get location, load data or copy into that location, or create external table

Comment: Could you share the steps ?. I know to create  a table. But I am not sure how to describe formatted to get location and load data into that location or create external table

Answer (score 0):

If you want managed table, then create it without location specified

```
CREATE TABLE dsk.node
(
    district  string,
    zone  string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED dsk.node;` and check the location, see [the manual](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_describe.html).

Then load data into location from DESCRIBE command above, if you have the data already loaded into some other location, just copy it using `hdfs dfs -cp` [command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/file_system_shell.html#cp).

Comment: The above approach did not work. Still facing the same issue