# changing hive external table to internal table in the same database also drops the data from the another table

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-table

I have been trying to drop a hive external table using the statement

> alter table $tableName set tblproperties('EXTERNAL' = 'FALSE');

after I pass these properties and do a

> DROP TABLE TABLENAME;

this command also drops the data from the other hive tables in that 
database.

Please can anyone suggest me why is it doing so? also if there is any way 
where we can only delete one external table which is mentioned without
loosing the other data.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME set tblproperties('EXTERNAL' = 'FALSE');
 drop table tablename;
```

Comment: This is possible if there are other tables with location pointing to the same location.

Comment: yeah I figured out but thanks for confirming appreciate that leftjoin

Comment: See this answer with tests please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038932/2700344

Comment: helped me a lot thanks again bud.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop managed table in Hive, its location with data files also gets dropped. And technically possible to create many tables, both managed and external on top of the same location, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038932/2700344) So, such scenario is quite possible. Some other table created with the same location will be emptied as well. Actually, data and table in Hive are loosely connected things. Table in Hive is a metastore information about location, schema, SerDe, statistics, access privileges, etc. And data is being stored in HDFS/S3 or other compatible filesystem. You can use some other means to drop data or load data, like `hadoop fs -rm` command, not only managed table in Hive.