# Is there a way to give a "second name" to a table in Hive so that a user can refer to either name of the table and would retrieve the same thing?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to be able to refer to tables with a certain naming schema to make my code uniform, but I am pulling tables from different environments with different naming schema.  If I want all my tables to have names like `example_table_1` and `example_table_2`, but the second one is something like `TB_ex_2`, is there a way to give that table an attribute so that I can also call `select * from database.example_table_2`, and it will know to refer to `TB_ex_2`?

I understand that I can alias tables, e.g. `select * from TB_ex_2 example_table_2`, but I am trying to avoid that.  Renaming each table is also not an option, because those names need to be retained to identify which environment they are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not support synonyms. The workaround is to [create a view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateView):

```
CREATE VIEW table2 
  AS SELECT * from table1;
```

Also you can [create many tables on top of the same location(data)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038932/2700344).